# Execute java code on remote system via ssh

Tags: java, ssh

I want to run a java program on my local PC which connects to a remote PC with ssh and executes some methods (java code, not bash scripts!) there. I found for example `JSch` which enables the ssh connection with and remote execution of code with something like

```
JSch jsch=new JSch();
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(passwd);
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
```

(from http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html)

or `ssxcute` which can be used with

```
ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("ip ", "username","password");
ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);      
ssh.connect();
CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand("echo 123");
ssh.exec(sampleTask);
```

(from https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/)

but what I want to do is something like

```
...
ssh.connect();
MyExecuteClass execClass = new MyExecuteClass();
ssh.exec(execClass.runLongJob(a, b, c));
MyReturn return = ssh.getReturnValue();
```

Is this possible? The objects `a,b,c` would have to be transmitted to the remote system, as well as all global variables, other classes, imports,... And the return value of the method must be returned somehow... If other objects are modified in the `runLongjob` method those changes have to be send back to the local PC as well.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do basically not only requires your objects to be serialized, transmitted and deserialized on the remote system, but also that a Java VM is present and started on the host and has the classes for your transmitted instances in its class path. I doubt you will find an out-of-the-box solution for that. You could use something like RMI to communicate with a running JVM on the remote host, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any frameworks to do specifically what you describe. The closest thing that comes to mind is to use web services. They allow you to define service running on a remote server which answers requests. The requests and responses can contain complex data structures. There are mature libraries for developing web services in java.

See these:

- [Introduction to Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijti.html)
- [Building Web Services with JAX-WS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html)